# Double Integral Question2

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\int\int_S xdydz+dzdx+xz^2dxdy$$

Where $S$ is the outer side of the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ in the first octant.

I need some hint to approach this problem.

Comment: Please check:  the very first summand in the integrand shouldn't  be $\;x\,dy\,\color{red}{dz}\;$ ?

Comment: You may use Gauss Divergence Theorem!

Comment: @Kunnysan Can this  problem be approached without any theorem just using double integration and substitution etc ?

Comment: Of course it can be done. Just parametrize the surface canonically. $x=\cos \theta \cos \varphi, y= \cos \theta \sin \varphi, z= \sin \varphi $ and plug in them in your integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: assuming the first summand of the integral is $\,x\,dy\,dz\;$ , we have

== Stokes Theorem (also called the Curl Theorem);

== Now put

$$F(P,Q,R):\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3\;,\;P,Q,R:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;\;\left\{\begin{align*}\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}&=x\\\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}&=1\\\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}&=xz^2\end{align*}\right.$$

Therefore, we're given the curf of the vector field, and the normal vector to $\,z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\,$ (towards outside the surface) is

$$\bf n:=(-z_x\,,\,-z_y\,,\,1)=\left(\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\,,\,\frac y{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\,,\,1\right)\;$$

Thus:

$$\text{curl}\,(F)\cdot\bf n=\frac{x^2+y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}+xz^2$$

Now, in the first octant on the $\,xy-$plane, the given unit sphere cuts the half unit semicircle $\,x^2+y^2=1\;,\;\;0\le x,y\le 1\;$ , which we can parametrize as

$$x=r\cos t\;,\;\;y=r\sin t\;,\;\;0\le r\le 1\;,\;\;0\le t\le \frac\pi2$$

So passing to polar coordinates we get that out integral is

$$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}r\left(\frac{r^2\cos^2t+r\sin t}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}+r\cos t(1-r^2)\right)dt\,dr=$$

$$=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{r^3}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\cos^2t+\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\sin t+r^2(1-r^2)\cos t\right)dt\,dr=$$

$$=\int\limits_0^1\left(\frac{r^3}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\left.\left.\frac{t+\cos t\sin t}2\right|_0^{\pi/2}-\left.\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\cos t\right|_0^{\pi/2}+r^2(1-r^2)\sin t\right|_0^{\pi/2}\right)dr=$$

$$=\frac\pi4\frac12\int\limits_0^1(-r^2)\frac{-2r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr+\frac12\int\limits_0^1(-r)\frac{-2r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr+\int\limits_0^1(r^2-r^4)dr=\;\ldots\ldots$$

Not the nicest thing but it already is ready, if I didn't make some mistake(s) here and there, to integrate by parts (and later a little trigonometric substitution)...